# Not able to bind gridview in vb.net in desktop application

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource

I have a gridview in which I am assigning the dataset as datasource in my program.

My Form_Load() event is:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=HCL-43AF369E5A0;Initial Catalog=Exam;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    cn.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from Contact", cn)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
    cn.Close()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

End Sub
```

What is the error in my code? I have debugged the code and found that the dataset fetches the data but not able to bind it to gridview.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign a `Datatable` as `DataGridView1.DataSource`. Not the DataSet. Use `ds.Tables()` property.

Answer (score 0):

**formal ways is**

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=HCL-43AF369E5A0;Initial Catalog=Exam;Integrated Security=True")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand        
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
cn.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from Contact", cn)
da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds)                    // edit here like      da.fill(ds, "table name")
cn.Close()

DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
DataGridView1.DataMember = "table name"
```

// table name will be any not the same as in your database

Your dataset is actually a data which you get by executing your query like "select * from tablename"

even you can have more than one table in a dataset so its formal method to give datamember name.